# CSS multiple font-families?

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
body {
 background-color: silver;
 color: white;
 padding: 20px;
 font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

What does it mean when there are **multiple csv font** `families`, like above?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means that the font will fall back to the next font listed if the client's browser doesn't have the prior font available.

By listing out multiple fonts, you can ensure the client gets to see the font you want to display even if the first font you have listed is not available in their browser.

In your example:

```
body {
  background-color: silver;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

`Arial` will fallback to `Verdana` which will fall back to `sans-serif`

Best practice:

> Start with the font you want, and always end with a generic family, to let the browser pick a similar font in the generic family, if no other fonts are available.

As an interesting tidbit font-families can be significant on a [character by character basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family):

> The font-family property specifies a list of fonts, from highest priority to lowest. Font selection does not simply stop at the first font named in the list that is on the user's system. Rather, font selection is done one character at a time, so that if an available font does not have a glyph that can display a character needed, the later available fonts are tried. However, this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6 or earlier.

Comment: It is useful when you are using a non-system font ( e.g. a font the user has to download to see it displayed on your website): if you specify a fallback font, the user will see it while the remote font is being downloaded on its device. If you do not, the user will see nothing.

Comment: thanks this makes sense.  So "sans-serif" is a generic family?  Meaning the browser will choose the appropriate default sans-serif font?

Comment: Assume, we have font Arial and "Hiragino Sans GB" in our page. If one sentence contains both Chinese and English characters. Browser uses Arial to render English characters, but uses "Hiragino Sans GB" to render Chinese. Browser will check right font one character by one.

Answer (score 2):

They're fallback options.  The "sans-serif" is a generic family meaning the browser will select a default font that is also sans-serif.